# Unzipping the content of a file

Tags: java

I have an application where Service A will provide a zipped data to Service B. And service B needs to unzip it.

Service A has an exposes method getStream and it gives ByteArrayInputStream as output and the data init is zipped data.

However passing that to GzipInputStream gives Not in Gzip format exception.

```
InputStream ins = method.getInputStream();
GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(ins);
```

This gives an exception. When the file is dumped in Service A the data is zipped. So getInputStream gives the zipped data.

How to process it ans pass it to the GzipInputStream?

Regards
Dheeraj Joshi

Answer (score 1):

If it zipped, then you must use `ZipInputstream`.

Answer (score 1):

It does depend on the "zip" format. There are multiple formats that have the zip name (zip, gzip, bzip2, lzip) and different formats call for different parsers.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_archive_formats
http://www.codeguru.com/java/tij/tij0115.shtml
http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch25_01.htm

If you are using zip then try this code:

```
public void doUnzip(InputStream is, String destinationDirectory) throws IOException {
    int BUFFER = 2048;

    // make destination folder
    File unzipDestinationDirectory = new File(destinationDirectory);
    unzipDestinationDirectory.mkdir();

    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is);

    // Process each entry
    for (ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry(); entry != null; entry = zis
            .getNextEntry()) {

        File destFile = new File(unzipDestinationDirectory, entry.getName());

        // create the parent directory structure if needed
        destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        try {
            // extract file if not a directory
            if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                // establish buffer for writing file
                byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

                // write the current file to disk
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
                BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,
                        BUFFER);

                // read and write until last byte is encountered
                for (int bytesRead; (bytesRead = zis.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1;) {
                    dest.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                dest.flush();
                dest.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    is.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    UnzipInputStream unzip = new UnzipInputStream();
    try {
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("test.zip"));
        unzip.doUnzip(fis, "output");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The file content was zipped using GZipOutputStream

Comment: Are you sure the file is not corrupted? Try then to save the file locally and use an external application to see if you can unzip it. If you can, it is a problem in the code. If not, the file is corrupted, or it is another format